# Zip epub using 7zip and issue with exlude file

Tags: bash, 7-zip, epub

I've many epub as folders need to convert it to .epub compressed
so i created bash script to that ..which are 
compress the epub folder to zip then rename it to .epub using 7-zip

btw i was try to use zip instead of 7-zip but i face issue with some files are content arabic character like

```
   السوق في الغرب.xhtml
```

after compressed using zip i got the file has been renamed to something unreadable like

```
  #?#?##?#??#####?#?.xhtml
```

Causing corrupt the epub file 
therefor I've use 7zip and seems it's fine no issue but I've small issue 
before in zip i was use like that

```
zip -X file.zip mimetype
zip -rg file.zip * -x mimetype
mv file.zip file.epub
```

and working except the above issue , now i try to do the same with 7z but i face issue with exclude the mimetype i got and error 
    Error:
    Incorrect command line

here my script

```
for i in *; do
7z a -tzip $i.zip mimetype
7z a -tzip $i.zip * -x!mimetype
rename *.zip *.epub
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the exclamation mark because of the shell, like this:

```
7z a -tzip $i.zip * -x\!mimetype
```